# Stopping a door when it touches the player or wall

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to make a door open and stops when it touches a wall or the player. I have tagged the wall, door and player and this is my script so far.

```
var doorDynamic = false;
function Start () {

}

function Update () {
if(doorDynamic == true)
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime*128);

}

function OnCollisionEnter(hit:Collision     ){
    doorDynamic=false;
}
```

May you share your scripting knowledge with me here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both your player and the door have colliders attached to them and they are at the right size, if your not sure try attaching a mesh collider. Its the least efficiant collider but at least you know that it will follow the outlines of your mesh.

It also looks like your delta time might be a little fast, there is a possibility that it goes right through the player before it gets a chance to check for a collision.